# How can I split cells in a certain way?

Tags: excel

I have a list of cells that contain data about subjects. These subjects contain two languages at the same time and I need to separate these two languages with the same structure. The cell has been structured like this:

turkishword1 = englishword1 ; turkishword2 = englishword2

I need to separate the cell into parts ";" between each subject.

Like this;

```
COLUMN1
turkishword1 ; turkishword2

COLUMN2
englishword1 ; englishword2
```

[image: you can easily see what I want in this picture;]

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub parseIT()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, p1 As String, p2 As String
    Dim arr1, arr2, a

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 2 To N
        p1 = ""
        p2 = ""
        arr1 = Split(Cells(i, 1).Text, ";")
        For Each a In arr1
            arr2 = Split(a, "=")
            p1 = p1 & ";" & arr2(0)
            p2 = p2 & ";" & arr2(1)
        Next a
        Cells(i, 2) = Mid(p1, 2)
        Cells(i, 3) = Mid(p2, 2)
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

This assumes that the data starts in row #2 of column **A**.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Office 365 or later you can use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"=",";"),";",REPT(" ",999)),((ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,";",""))+1))-1)*2+(COLUMN(A:A)-1))*999+1,999)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter in stead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

After entering in B2 and using Ctrl-Shift-Enter, copy over and down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And, if you have Excel 2010+, you can use `Power Query` (aka `Get&Transform`)

Most can be done from the User interface except for the custom columns

- Add an Index Column
- Split the column by the `semicolon`
- Select the Index column and `Unpivot other columns`
- Remove the Attribute column
- Split the column by the `equal sign`
- `Trim` the value columns (to remove leading/trailing spaces)
- `Group` the rows by the Index column with Operation = `All Rows`
- **Add Custom Column**

  - New column Name:  Subject 1
  - Formula: =Table.Column([Grouped],"Value.1")
- Extract values with `;` as the custom delimiter
- **Add Custom Column**

  - New column Name:  Subject 2
  - Formula: =Table.Column([Grouped],"Value.2")
- Extract values with `;` as the custom delimiter
- Remove the `Index` and `Table` columns

If you add/remove items or rows from the original table, you can easily update the results with a mouse-click.

Here is the **M-code** which you could just paste into the Advanced Editor from the Power Query interface:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"subjects", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Added Index", "subjects", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"subjects.1", "subjects.2", "subjects.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"subjects.1", type text}, {"subjects.2", type text}, {"subjects.3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("=", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Value.1", "Value.2"}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Value.1", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Value.2", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Trimmed Text",{{"Value.1", type text}, {"Value.2", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type2", {"Index"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Index=number, Value.1=text, Value.2=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Subject 1", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Value.1")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Subject 1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), " ; "), type text}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Subject 2", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Value.2")),
    #"Extracted Values1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"Subject 2", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), " ; "), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values1",{"Index", "Grouped"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, use the Text to Columns tool for the whole array:

- Data -> Text to Columns -> Delimited -> Semicolon -> Destination=C3

Assuming there are max 3 items per cell, you will see the separated data in columns C:E.

Next, you use the TRIM function:

- F3 = TRIM(C3), copy to right and down

Finally, use these 2 functions for subject1 and subject2:

```
=LEFT(F3;FIND("=";F3)-1)&IF(LEN(G3)>0;"; "&LEFT(G3;FIND("=";G3)-1);"")&IF(LEN(H3)>0;"; "&LEFT(H3;FIND("=";H3)-1);"")
=RIGHT(F3;LEN(F3)-FIND("=";F3)-1)&IF(LEN(G3)>0;" ; "&RIGHT(G3;LEN(G3)-FIND("=";G3)-1);"")&IF(LEN(H3)>0;" ; "&RIGHT(H3;LEN(H3)-FIND("=";H3)-1);"")
```

Again, this is for max 3 items (but could be less).

And this is how it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjL2g.jpg

(sorry, cannot post pictures without reputation)